# Get notified when cursor position changed in Eclipse TextEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, selectionchanged

I am developing a plugin to eclipse and I want to add some actions to the context menu. But actually I wanted to prepare results beforehead according to the text selection in the editor and just show them when the menu item will be selected. 
I followed that article http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html - all interfaces (`ISelectionListener`, `ISelectionChangedListener` etc) allow to handle the `SelectionChanged` event, but editor counts changing only when length of selection also changes - so the simple click in the editor doesn't fire the event, although I want to get the word (for example) as a selection if cursor is inside the word now and lenght is 0.

So the question is - what is the simpliest solution for traking down cursor position/offset/selections with zero lengh value changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you have to use KeyListener and MouseListener as well. For e.g take a look at org.eclipse.jface.text.PaintManager, and it listens to all these events.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Couldn't find where I can add my own Key and Mouse listeners to the editor only. It seems extending and then replacing the default editor is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending `TextEditor` you can override `handleCursorPositionChanged()` method to fire your event and use `getCursorPosition()` to get the cursor position as a `String`.

Comment: do mention what are the reasons and why you have suggested this answer.and read FAQ to know, how to give answers in suitable way.